# I want to change the page title dynamically based on the URL

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, page-title

I have wordpress website which is based in U.S. and I have a primary service page and it URL is **[www.example.com/service-page](http://www.example.com/service-page)**

Using this single primary service page, I rewrite the URL and generated 51 state based URL's like below

**[www.example.com/service-page-georgia](http://www.example.com/service-page-georgia)**

**[www.example.com/service-page-florida](http://www.example.com/service-page-florida)**

**[www.example.com/service-page-new-york](http://www.example.com/service-page-new-york)**

Each page has different content, but the title of all 51 state page is same **"Service Page"**.

I want to change all the 51 state page titles based on the URL. For example

If I landed on **[www.example.com/service-page-georgia](http://www.example.com/service-page-georgia)**, the title should be **"Service Page Georgia"** likewise I want it for all 51 state page.

What shall I do, if I want to get dynamic title for each state based pages.

**Below is my code for URL Rewrite:**

```php
function mp_rewrite(){                   
          add_rewrite_rule('^(services-page)-([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&usstate=$matches[2]','top');   
         }

       //Function to Flush the Rewrite rules
        function mp_flush_rewrite_rules()
        {
            global $wp_rewrite;
            $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
        }
        
         //Function to grab the query parameter and store it.
        function mp_query_vars($vars){
            $vars[] = 'usstate';
            return $vars;
        }
```

Comment: You have to use the `the_title` filter, along with `get_query_vars`, etc.